# What is the preference of SQLiteQueryBuilder?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

`SQLiteQueryBuilder`  has method:

```
 public Cursor query (SQLiteDatabase db, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder)
```

also `SQLiteDataBase` has method:

```
 public public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

Is there any reason to use `SQLiteQueryBuilder.query` method instead of `SQLiteDataBase.query`

and which advantages does it gives?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230049/sqlitequerybuilder-query-vs-sqlitedatabase-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SQLiteQueryBuilder` helps to construct queries that are more complex than those supported by the `SQLiteDatabase` functions (for example, subqueries).

If your particular query does not need any of those complex features, you do not need to use `SQLiteQueryBuilder`.
(But it might make sense if your code happens to be organized so that it's easier if all queries use `SQLiteQueryBuilder`.)