# SQLiteQueryBuilder.query() vs SQLiteDatabase.query()

Tags: android, sqlite

What's the difference between these two approaches?
For me it seems that the only benefit of SQLiteDatabase is its ability to work with different databases. Am I right?

Comment: Did you notice, that `SQLiteQueryBuilder#query()` has a `SQLiteDatabase` as it's first argument?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The primary method is `SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery()`. Both `SQLiteDatabase#query()` and `SQLiteQueryBuilder` are just helpers to compose the SQL.

The `SQLiteDatabase#query()` can only compose simple queries from one table. The `SQLiteQueryBuilder` can create joins, unions and such. Since `SQLiteQueryBuilder` is an extra object, you'd only construct it if you need it's power.

Personally I think that any non-trivial SQL is easier to read as SQL than as pieces composed with helper like this, so I'd use `rawQuery` over `SQLiteQueryBuilder`, but that's a matter of taste and how well you know SQL.  The `SQLiteQueryBuilder` might also be useful if you have some common subqueries that you want to compose together in different ways.

In fact I would prefer to use prepared statements, because compilation of SQL is slow compared to it's execution, and because it avoids doing string operations on potentially untrusted values. I couldn't find the API at first, because for some strange reason it is called [`SQLiteDatabase#compileStatement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String)) rather than the usual [`prepare`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) used in the underlying C API.

Comment: "I would prefer  to use prepared statements".
What about this:
SQLiteStatement sqlInsert = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?)");
sqlInsert.bindLong(1, a);
sqlInsert.bindLong(2, b);
sqlInsert.execute();

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul, that's prepared statement, except the function is called `compileStatement` instead of the more common `prepare` [used in the C API](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html). It is the preferred method.

Answer (score 4):

SQLiteQueryBuilder is useful if you want to do joins on multiple tables.  It has several convenience methods for that, if you view the source-code on GrepCode: [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java/?v=source)

Otherwise, I cannot think of a solid reason to use SQLiteQueryBuilder over other approaches for querying the database.