# SQLite Exception: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE person_table SET person_name=? WHERE _id =

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting this exception at runtime:

> SQLite Exception: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
>   UPDATE person_table SET person_name=? WHERE _id =

Below I am posted the codes related to that.I am mentioned the error line 51 and 56th line in below codes.

**Stacktrace:**

```
12-23 02:02:19.060: E/SQLiteLog(3011): (1) near "=": syntax error
12-23 02:02:19.060: D/AndroidRuntime(3011): Shutting down VM
12-23 02:02:19.060: W/dalvikvm(3011): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a8bba8)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011): Process: com.android.timesheet, PID: 3011
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE person_table SET person_name=? WHERE _id =
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1572)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.timesheet.database.PersonDatabaseHelper.updateData(PersonDatabaseHelper.java:51)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.timesheet.ModifyMember.onClick(ModifyMember.java:56)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-23 02:02:19.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3011):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**PersonDatabaseHelper.java:**

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    private static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
    public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int updateData(String member_id, String memberName) {
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, memberName);
        int i = database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, --->51th line Error
                PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + member_id, null);
        return i;
    } 

    public void deleteData(String memberID) {  
        database.delete(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + "="
                + memberID, null);
    }


    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

**ModifyMember.java:**

```
public class ModifyMember extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText et;
    Button edit_bt, delete_bt;

    String member_id;

    PersonDatabaseHelper dbcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.modify_member);

        dbcon = new PersonDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());  
    //  dbcon.open();    

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mem_id);
        edit_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_bt_id);
        delete_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_bt_id);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String memberID = i.getStringExtra("memberID");
        String memberName = i.getStringExtra("memberName");

        member_id=memberID;  
//      member_id = Long.parseLong(memberID);

        et.setText(memberName);

        edit_bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete_bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.update_bt_id:
            String memName_upd = et.getText().toString();
            dbcon.updateData(member_id, memName_upd);  ----> 56th line error
            this.returnHome();
            break;

        case R.id.delete_bt_id:

            dbcon.deleteData(member_id);
            this.returnHome();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void returnHome() {

        Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                NewProjects.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(home_intent);
    }

}
```

Anybody can help me to resolve this issue.Thank you.

Comment: Don't use string pasting to generate SQL statements; it's both slow and insecure. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: So your `member_id` is an empty string - have you considered debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
    database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, --->51th line Error
            PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + member_id, null);
```

into

```
    database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, 
            PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " =?" , new String[]{member_id});
```

Comment: Error solved but it didn't update the new names.For example:if I give a new name for updation,it didn't get updated.

Comment: @User10 may be your member_id has problem..once debug it

Comment: Yes I debug it.it returns null in logcat.I used this line `Log.d("MemID","Test"+member_id);` in UpdateData method.Then in logcat it returns `12-23 04:02:52.600: D/MemID(3462): Test
`

Comment: @User10 so your intent data is null..once check your intent data where you are passing

Comment: I am added the ? before = solved my problem,that you pointed out.Can you elaborate how does it solve the error with small explanation

Comment: @User10 all ? are in the predefined method replaced by their values before executing the Sqlite statement..

Comment: Not all.only this line `database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, 
            PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " =?" , new String[]{member_id});`

Comment: @User10 yeah.There is class called SqliteQueryBuilder which will prepare the statements for you..for more check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230049/sqlitequerybuilder-query-vs-sqlitedatabase-query

Comment: much helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
public int updateData(String member_id, String memberName) {
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, memberName);
    int i = database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, --->51th line Error
            PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " = " + member_id, null);
    return i;
}
```

By:

```
public int updateData(String member_id, String memberName) {
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, memberName);
    int i = database.update(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, cvUpdate, --->51th line Error
            PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {member_id});
    return i;
}
```